# android: Android Studio: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android

Unable to find the reason for this error in the code, it suddenly prompted an error on second line that Unexpected Token. kindly help. Thanks in advance!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".JobSeekicious">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/overcast"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Profile"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Edit" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="106dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/sid_required"
                app:border_width="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/userBtns"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="First Name "
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Last name "
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_signup_as"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Password "
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_gender"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Re-type Password "
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_dOb"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Country "
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_country"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="City"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/_my_profile_city"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/_my_profile_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/overcast"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="SAVE"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/_my_profile_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Unable to find the reason for this error in the code, it suddenly prompted an error on second line that Unexpected Token.

kindly help. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: May I have the error in message?

Comment: Somehow, you have about 8000 spaces between the `<?xml version...>` tag, and the opening `<LinearLayout>` tag.

Comment: Please post the error

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add viewgroup onsecond line. Please add LinearLayout and try to run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".JobSeekicious">
```

Change to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".JobSeekicious">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a mistake in pasting code here.My actual code has the viewGroup. But it did not solved the problem though i removed the first line 
 
and the error was removed. I don't know how but it worked for me.!!!
Thankyou all.